# C# Optimisation Combining Return Statements

Tags: c#, compilation, compiler-optimization

I have written a function in C# using Visual Studio and decided to see what it looks like when compiled with the 'optimize code' build flag enabled.

I inspected the DLL with dnSpy and noticed the if statements have been removed. This is causing the neighbour.data array to be accessed every time the function is called, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Here is the function in Visual Studio:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
protected bool DrawFaceXNegative(int j, int k, int chunkPosition, Chunk neighbour)
{
    // These two if statements are here to prevent an array access if possible
    if (chunkPosition == 0)
        return false;

    if (neighbour == null)
        return true;

    return neighbour.data[31 * Constants.ChunkSize + j + k * Constants.ChunkSizeSquared].index == 0;
}
```

Here is the function in dnSpy:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
protected bool DrawFaceXNegative(int j, int k, int chunkPosition, Chunk neighbour)
{
    return chunkPosition != 0 && (neighbour == null || neighbour.data[992 + j + k * 1024].index == 0);
}
```

Changing the logic to if-else statements produced the same result. Is there a way to prevent this optimisation from happening?

As a side question, what is causing the compiler to believe that the produced function is more optimised?

Comment: As far as I can see, it's only more optimal in terms of the number of bytes of IL generated, performance would be identical.

Comment: Can you please clarify "This is causing the neighbour.data array to be accessed every time the function is called"? As @BradleySmith said code is absolutely identical and it is possible that decompiler just got IL->C# conversion not the way you like. Compare IL of "optimized" and debug builds of the method to confirm.

Comment: You code uses `chunkPosX` rather then `chunkPosition`. I think that is a copy mistake

Comment: _"...This is causing the neighbour.data array to be accessed every time the function is called..."_ - what makes you think that? That is only true if `chunkPosition != 0 && (neighbour == null`.

Comment: @MickyD from Christopher's answer I wasn't aware that the rest of the && calculation would stop if the first part of the condition was false. Thank you all for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return chunkPosition != 0 && ...
```

is doing the exact same thing as

```
  if (chunkPosition == 0)
        return false;
```

In the case that chunkPosition is 0, it:

1. Stops the rest of the calculation, per && rules
2. It returns false

If this part evaluates true, the return value will be `true && (neighbour == null || neighbour.data[992 + j + k * 1024].index == 0);` - so whatever the elipses results in.

&& connected things are executed, until you hit the first false.

|| connected things are executed, until the you hit the first true.

If you want all the code to be executed all the time, I think the single character version is the droid you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware that && rules would cause the rest of the calculation to stop.